# On screen mobile keyboard is hiding the HTML textarea when in focus

Tags: javascript, android, css, firefox, flexbox

I have a cheap $70 Android 2.3.6 smartphone (320px 480px screen) with the latest Firefox Mobile on it. I'm trying to get a pretty basic webpage going which has a textarea on it. Whenever I click into the textarea on the screen to enter text, the onscreen keyboard pushes all the HTML off the screen and you can't see what is being typed (very frustrating). It only appears to be happening on Firefox. The inbuilt Android browser works fine.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">         
        <style>
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display: -ms-box;
                display: flex;
                -webkit-flex-direction: column;
                -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
                min-height: 100vh;
            }

            header, footer {
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                height: 35px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .main {
                -webkit-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex: 1;
                flex: 1;
                background-color: #00cc00;
                height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
                height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
                height: calc(100% - 50px);
                text-align: center;
            }

            .textEntry {
                height: 50px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>header</header>
        <div class="main">main</div>
        <textarea class="textEntry" placeholder="text here"></textarea>
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have thought about using a media query to perhaps hide other elements seeing the problem might be that there isn't enough vertical space on the screen to show everything with the onscreen keyboard which takes up half the screen. Maybe something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-height : 220px) {
    footer, .main, header {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But that isn't working reliably. Is there any other fixes/tricks that can be applied here?

Thankyou!

Comment: To be honest this sounds more like a bug in Firefox Mobile than something you should be trying to rectify in your code. Have you thought about filing on with a reduced testcase at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi#h=dupes|Firefox+for+Android

Comment: You're using the wrong properties with the ms prefixes.  IE10 uses this draft:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/